# Installing PMD 5.0.4 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

Can anybody tell me how to install PMD in Eclipse. I have downloaded PMD 5.0.4 from the following link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/latest/download?source=files

When I add this archive file in Eclipse install option I am getting an error stating that "It could not find the file specified".

Comment: You should install the PMD plugin for eclipse http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.4/integrations.html#eclipse

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. In that link, plugin version 5.0.4 is not  available(The highest version available is 4.0.0). Could you tell me where i can download pmd-eclipse plugin 5.0.4?

Comment: Plugin versions and PMD engine versions are not synchronized, just install version 4 of the plugin.

Answer (score 10):

Just follow the directions on http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/ 
I copied the direction here for you so you don't even have to click !!

In Eclipse, click on Help -> Install New Software...

Click on Add..
Enter the following:

Name: PMD for Eclipse Update Site

URL: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

and click OK.

You should see PMD for Eclipse 4. Select the checkbox next to it and click Next >.

You'll need to accept the license and confirm you want to install a plugin that is not digitally signed. Go ahead and install it anyway.

Restart eclipse.

Comment: I tried installing this plugin, but keep getting `Unknown Host: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/content.xml
Unknown Host: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/content.xml
sourceforge.net` error, any idea?

Comment: Please note, the update site [has changed](https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/issues/19).

The new update site is: https://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/updates/

Answer (score 3):

You should not download anything. Instead, simply add following URL as new update site in Eclipse -> Help -> Install new sofware:

```
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse
```

Then select appropriate Eclipse PMD plugin and you are done.

Comment: Hi, When i add this link, I am getting the following error, **or.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException** -> HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code(302):http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse/content.xml

Comment: This is strange. I have Eclipse 4.2.2 (Juno), and it works just fine.

Comment: Even I've encountered this error in Eclipse Kepler. Did u found any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Please use eclipse update site http://www.acanda.ch/eclipse-pmd/release/latest

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a firewall?

Check the connection settings in your eclipse.

Comment: how firewall , might be affecting , what to check , how to any insight ??

Answer (score 0):

Simply goto Eclipse -> Help -> Marketplace
From here search "PMD" in the box and select the PMD plugin(not eclipse-pmd).

Click on install and restart eclipse to use.