# How to manually install JAutodoc in eclipse kepler?

Tags: eclipse-kepler, jautodoc

I do not have access to the internet from eclipse so I can not add software using update sites.  I have tried several different methods but none seems to be working.

I am using the JBoss Dev Studio version of kepler, but I figured this might be a general eclipse question.

Tried Help- Install New Software - Add... - browse to zip file and I get "could not find jar:file:/blahblahblah/jautodoc_1.10.0.zip!/"  Nothing.

Tried unzipping it so we end up with eclipse/dropins/jautodoc_1.10.0/[features | plugins followed by restart. Nothing.

Tried unzipping it so we end up with eclipse/dropins/[features | plugins] followed by restart.  Still nothing.

What is the definitive way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PMD 5.0.4 in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672623/installing-pmd-5-0-4-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The correct place to install the **plugin** and **features** folders is in

> $ECLIPSE_HOME/studio/dropins/jautodoc

I had to create the **dropins** and **jautodoc** folders.

Perhaps it goes without saying that you can name the sub-folder containing features and plugins to whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps for Installation:

1. Download jautodoc_1.11.0.zip file from :

   http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/index.html#download
2. Unzip the jautodoc_1.11.0.zip file from the eclipse folder.
   Verify the following files get copied:

   Plugin folder :

   ```
   net.sf.jautodoc.velocity_1.11.0.jar

   net.sf.jautodoc_1.11.0.jar
   ```

   Features folder :

   ```
   net.sf.jautodoc.feature_1.11.0
   ```
3. Restart eclipse.
   The JAutodoc feature should be available in Windows --> Preferences

Usage :

Select the whole file or method or attribute --> Rightclick --> Add Javadoc

Visit the following link for further info :

http://www.roseindia.net/IDE/Eclipse/jautodoc-plugin.shtml