# How to configure and use PMD for Improving Code Quality in Eclipse?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I want to use PMD for Improving Code Quality in Eclipse and as per mentioned in
some PMD links I have downloaded it from eclipse marketplace and installed  but when I right click on project it's not showing PMD option.

So can anyone help me how to configure PMD for eclipse.

Comment: Hej Ranjeet,
check the first answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672623/installing-pmd-5-0-4-in-eclipse)
If you have installed PMD from the UpdateSite you can configure from Window -> Preferences -> PMD

Answer (score 1):

For the PMD plug-in eclipse-pmd (the one from the marketplace) you'll find the PMD settings in the project properties. There are instructions on [how to get started with eclipse-pmd](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/getting-started.html) on its website.

Answer (score 1):

Ranjeet the eclipse plugin installation is not enough. YOu have to configure your project to use the PMD in eclipse.
Also you have to define your rules to use. Very good tutorials are:
http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/pmd/

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h68dWYHQb0