# JAD Eclipse plugin not working, No repository found at http://feeling.sourceforge.net/update

Tags: eclipse, jad

It seems that [JAD plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jadclipse) is not working with the latest Eclipse. After searching it in `Eclipse MarketPlace` when I try to install it shows an error box with the error details

```
No repository found at http://feeling.sourceforge.net/update
```

I have encountered this error on following

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200


Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.7.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201511261048
Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PMD 5.0.4 in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672623/installing-pmd-5-0-4-in-eclipse)

Comment: @SamuelJackson What criteria did you use to determine that ?

Comment: This question poses a general question which the directions to install a plugin are the same - just swap plugin name - .   While the solution you provided is one of the better ones, I must use the oldest version that I can find of "how do i install X plugin in eclipse" as the foundation.

Comment: This question is not about how to install plugin in eclipse. It's specifically related to `JAD`, as it was working with the older versions of eclipse and now it's not working anymore.

Comment: ... which follows the same plugin installation methods as pretty much every other plugin for Eclipse.   It's like asking "How do I make Notepad++ work with Windows", and then provide installation instructions, or "How do I copy an excel file" and show how to copy a file.  In these cases, the actual specific program or file type the instructions would be the same as any other program or file type respectively.

Comment: Question is more subtle than installing a plugin, JAD worked great on the older version of eclipse (before 4) however not it seems to be an abandoned project. Update repository no longer works, and when we install it via addons it initially doesn't open class files and when that issue is solved, plugin gives IOException for the class files. Answer for all these issues are present on this question. And if you think that it's as simple as installing a plugin in Eclipse, please post a solution. Because I know that I need it, along with other thousands of Java developers who use Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to install the JAD by manually putting `JAD Jar plugin` file into `Eclipse->dropins` directory.

**Solution**

1. Download JAR from below

   http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Download
2. Put the JAR inside eclipse dropins directory

> Eclipse
> --dropins

3. Restart Eclipse and verify that JAD is installed under

> Help -> Installation Details -> Plugins Tab

[image]

Now we should be able to use JAD.

**Note**: There's one other issue that we may encounter, that is even though JAD is installed it (JAD viewer) doesn't open the class files. As default viewer for class files in Eclipse comes in the way.

To remedy that we have to change the order of precedence of JAD class file viewer in eclipse file associations.

Following are the steps to do that.

1. Open `Window -> Preferences -> General -> viewers -> File Associations`
2. Click on the `*.class without source` in the pane below for **Associated
   viewers** remove the `Class File Viewer`. Now JAD should be the only viewer available. If it's not present click on `Add` and search for JAD and add it.
3. If we want we can add the `Class File Viewer` (Eclipse default) as secondary viewer, but as long as JAD is the first in the viewer list, it doesn't matter.
4. We may want to execute the same steps (1 to 3) for `*.class` files also. I'm notsure, but if we don't do that may be files with source (ie. Maven jars with source) won't open with the JAD viewer.

Following is a screenshot of the correct file association.

[image]

Comment: The installation did work, but for an unknown reason, the actual decompilation is not working. It's probably something on my end, so thanks for the answer!

Comment: Check the later part of the answer, you may be missing the correct file association for `JadClips viewer`. It's normal for new Eclilpse versions.

Comment: It's a runtime problem : `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jad"` but I don't have time to debug it at the moment so I'll fix later. At least, the plugin is installed ;) :).

Comment: I had problems with Mars.2. The file association works correctly, but the opened class file is empty. It seems jadClipse and the build-in decomplier interfere. So I unset the "Set Class Decompiler Viewer as default..." property in Java > Decomplier.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting an error such as `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jad"` after manually dropping the JAD jar into Eclipse, it means the jad.exe executable is not on the path.

You can manually point the Eclipse plugin to it:
Window > Preferences... > Java > JadClipse > Path to Decompiler.

You may have to restart Eclipse afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

From OP`s answer, I visited Download jar Page and copied the repo link

http://jadclipse.sf.net/update

Then I Performed following steps

1. Open Eclipse
2. click Help -> Install new software
3. Paste link or Add  new software site and hit Enter

It installs JDT Decompiler 3.4.0 which is supposibaly Jad`s latest version. propely. I tested installation but not working

Can anyone confirm is it same as previous version?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the project is not accessible on sourceforge anymore.

The developer opened a ticket a week ago : https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/12050/

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution. I'll post it here.

Comment: @11thdimension And what was that solution ? I've try to installed it but I still have the repository not found.

Comment: @Marc-Andre posted the answer today. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for Eclipse Junos 32 bit on Windows 7. May be useful for someone trying on earlier eclipse env.

1. Download jad for windows (jad158g.win.zip) from https://varaneckas.com/jad/  or http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html#download   Link: Jad 1.5.8g for Windows 9x/NT/2000 on Intel platform (238600 bytes).
   Unzip the downloaded jad158g.win.zip and extract the jad.exe to some path say C:\apps\jad\jad.exe
2. Download the Jadclipse jar (net.sf.jadclipse_x.x.x.jar)" from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/   or  http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Download
3. Copy the Jad Eclipse plugin jar to your Eclipse plugin folder Ex. C:\Java\eclipse-jee-juno-win32\plugins\net.sf.jadclipse_3.3.0.jar
4. Open Eclipse and navigate to Window –> Preferences –> Java –> Jadclipse
   Enter the exe path of jad 
   Path to decompiler: C:\apps\jad\jad.exe
   Directory for temporary files: C:\Users\xxx.net.sf.jadclipse
5. Restart Eclipse