# How to install PMD in eclipse Neon - Unable to find repository

Tags: pmd

How to install 5.0.4 pmd in eclipse Neon? I am getting some issue when I give URL and am using java 1.8 version. Could you please help me how to resolve that issue? My issue is below like

unable to find repository http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

Comment: So the 2013 question https://stackoverflow.com/q/17672623/6309 is obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

The update site [has changed](https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/issues/19).

Please use from now on: https://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/updates/

By the way, PMD 5.0.4 is very old and not supported anymore. See https://pmd.github.io for the current information.